# Xlookup issue with Indirect function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, xlookup

I am utilizing a xlookup with indirect references function with certain date ranges to determine the range of rows to search in. With 3k rows of data and repeating values this helped me pair down to non-repeating values so I don't have an errant value from an earlier entry. The xlookup initially worked great when I manually inputted range of rows to search in but when indirect was introduced I am getting my error message I programmed (leading me to believe there isn't an error with my function)

When I utilize the direct references (meaning I'd have to change the date ranges directly in formula) it works great!

```
`=xlookup(T3,Statistics!F203:F215,Statistics!A203:215,"Not Scheduled",1,1)`
```

However when I use indirect to reference the specific range (so that I can adjust the date range over one cell and the reference rows recalculate) I get the error message I programmed.

```
`=xlookup(T3,indirect(Statistics!Q11&":"&Statistics!R11),indirect(Statistics!T11&":"&Statistics!U11),"Not Scheduled",1,1)`
```

```
Q11=F203
R11=F215
T11=A203
U11=A215
```

The correct answer lies in Row F205 which is within the ranges specified in the function.

Usually I figure these out or find a typo when utilizing my functions but I'll be honest and say this has me stumped. The references on the other page are identical. Just for note I also tried a Concateate function to combine the two cells before calling indirect with the same result. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this would add verification to a transportation system instead of double entry across two systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see it, what I think you're missing is the name of the sheet. You're referencing to the cells but not clarifying that the INDIRECT function has to look into "Statistics". Try adding it:

```
=xlookup(T3,indirect("Statistics!"&Statistics!Q11&":"&Statistics!R11),indirect("Statistics!"&Statistics!T11&":"&Statistics!U11),"Not Scheduled",1,1)
```

About that 1 after "Not Scheduled", are you sure you don't want an exact match only? Meaning to use a 0 instead of 1

[image]

Comment: That was exactly what I was missing. I haven't used indirect frequently but it is very handy when I do. Thank you so much. Also this was admittedly the first time using xlookup so I was experimenting to make sure that wasn't my error right before making the post.